# java use object as double without explicit cast

Tags: java, object, casting, double, downcast

Say I have this:

```
Object obj = new Double(3.14);
```

Is there a way to use `obj` like a `Double` without explicitly casting it to `Double`? For instance, if I wanted to use the `.doubleValue()` method of `Double` for calculations.

Comment: Why don't you want to cast?

Comment: Because I want a truly generic means of handling Objects that are in a List and explicit casting would require the I write a ton of if-clauses. My curiosity lies in creating a more dynamic means of doing with Objects what I will/need.

Comment: Are generics not "truly generic" enough for you?

Comment: I apologize for the context switch, I though my original question would lead me to an answer but only left be feeling like I needed to explain more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this. `obj` is of type `Object` (even though it is a `Double` *instance*), and the `Object` class does not have such methods as `doubleValue()`. The proper way would indeed be to cast:

```
Double d = (Double) obj;
```

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do it if you can not cast is to [use reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html):

```
Object obj = new Double(3.14);

Method m1 = obj.getClass().getMethod("doubleValue");
System.out.println("Double value: " + m1.invoke(obj));

Method m2 = obj.getClass().getMethod("intValue");
System.out.println("Int value: " + m2.invoke(obj));
```

```
Double value: 3.14
Int value: 3
```

This is usually only useful in some limited corner cases - normally, casting, generics, or using some supertype is the right approach.

Comment: This is extremely useful! Thanks! It does not completely solve my issue but it certainly will help in the corner cases I do have to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.

Since your reference is to an `Object`, you will only have the methods which `Object` has at its disposal.

Note that you can use `Number`, which is the superclass of `Integer`, `Short`, etc and which defines `.doubleValue()`:

```
final Number n = new Double(2.0);
n.doubleValue(); // works
```

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can do is this

```
Number num = new Double(3.14);
double d= num.doubleValue();
```

You can only call methods that the compiler knows is available, not based on the runtime type of the objects.

In short `Object` doesn't have a doubleValue() method so you cannot call it.  You have to have a reference type which has the method you want to call.

Comment: So regardless, at runtime if I've got an Object there is absolutely no way to somehow use it like a Number/Double/etc.?

Comment: @Mastergeek not without casting it first.  You can toString(), hashCode(), equals() as Object has those methods.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. The instance `obj` is a reference to an `Object` and can see only the methods of the `Object` class. You must cast it to `Double` to use specific methods of the `Double` class.

Answer (score 0):

No!
The only alternative is to use:

```
obj.toString()
```

Or, to use as double:

```
Double.parseDouble(obj.toString())
```

But it is not a good practice. Certainly has some another good alternative to your case. Post your code